# Proof/Counterexample: Any two 6x6 matrices are similar of they have the same rank and same minimal polynomial

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-rank, minimal-polynomials

I am asked to prove or provide a counterexample for this claim:

Any two $6\times6$ matrices are similar of they have the same rank and same minimal polynomial.

I know two matrices are similar if they have the same Jordan form. I have a hunch that they are similar always in this case and no counterexample would exist but I don't know how to prove it.

Thanks in advance.

Edit: I found [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2520692/similar-nilpotent-matrices-with-same-minimal-polynomial-and-rank) answer which is along the similar lines but how to prove that the Jordan forms will be same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are
$$A=\begin{pmatrix}1&1&0&0&0&0\\
0&1&0&0&0&0\\
0&0&1&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&1&0&0\\
0&0&0&0&1&0\\
0&0&0&0&0&1
\end{pmatrix}$$
and
$$B=\begin{pmatrix}1&1&0&0&0&0\\
0&1&0&0&0&0\\
0&0&1&1&0&0\\
0&0&0&1&0&0\\
0&0&0&0&1&0\\
0&0&0&0&0&1
\end{pmatrix}$$
similar?
Both have rank $6$ and minimal polynomial $X^2-2X+1$. (This works already with $4\times 4$ matrices)